# Any differences from using IIS express over a web server

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

Im doing a final year project and it involves a MVC4 intranet application to be used for a real production company.

I have it working perfectly on the IIS express used in VS2012 and well tested. Now i have to do a demonstration of the application to the markers, would there be much difference from keeping it on localhost (IIS express) or would i be better to create a VM web server for the application. I don't want to be the latter if its practically the same as IIS express, so is there any advantages of one over the other? i also thought about web hosting but that defeats the intranet purpose.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Express is a web server for development, so comparing to a production purposed web server such as full IIS, http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview the differences are significant.